# Mongoose: How to slice the entire query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for a way to get M documents out of a particular query, starting at the Nth document, without rendering the entire collection at the `exec()` callback and then splice an array from there. I'm well aware of `.limit(x)` which works fine and dandy to get from 0 to x, but to my knowledge there is no way I select where does the query start limiting the number of documents, something like `limit(10)` starting from 5.

I tried something like this:

```
Model.find().sort({creationDate: -1}).where("_id").splice([5,10]).exec(function(err, data) {
                if(err) res.send(502, "ERROR IN DB DATABASE");
                res.send(data);
            });
```

But the resulting data consists of the entire collection.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.skip is what you are looking for

```
Model.find(...).sort(...).skip(5).limit(10).exec(....)
```